# Remove Decimal Point - Crystal Report Advanced

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010, crystal-reports-8.5

I want to get rid of this (.00) numbers from all the numeric fields. Example: (123.00) but I do not know how, Can you help me please.

Comment: https://www.itsupportguides.com/knowledge-base/crystal-reports/crystal-reports-remove-decimal-places-from-string/

Comment: ToText(field,0,"") will do the job for you...

Comment: Thank you for answering, but I have hundreds of reports, I want a general rule for all fields, greetings.

Comment: This sounds like a formatting issue, so either go into the format editor, pick a custom format, and then set Decimals to 1; or the easier way:  On the Formatting toolbar the last two buttons let you increase or decrease the precision (as well as other handy formatting features).